# Name for cognitive bias suggesting a person is special or important

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for the name of the cognitive bias that leads people to think that they are extraordinary in some aspect.

This is similar to [Illusory Superiority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illusory_superiority) but generalized to encompass uniqueness in general, not just positive traits.

It's the "*Why is it always me?*" bias.

**Added**
This is the belief that unusual things happen more often to *you*, and is typically caused by the fact that unusual things get more of your attention when they happen to you rather than when they happen to others.

**Clarification**
I'm not looking for a **disorder,** I'm looking for the name of the trait that is common in nearly everyone such that they think that things that they don't notice in other people is believed to only happen to them.

Comment: "American"? /duck

Comment: For some contexts, [_special snowflake_](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=special%20snowflake) may be appropriate, but I wouldn't use it for this concept in general.

Comment: I don't think it fits exactly, but it's worth considering: [*Egocentric bias*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egocentric_bias) In particular it mentions: *Besides simply claiming credit for positive outcomes, which might simply be self-serving bias, people exhibiting egocentric bias also cite themselves as overly responsible for negative outcomes of group behavior as well*

Comment: The self-messianic chosen-one delusional syndrome.

Comment: Most of the answers are suggesting some kind of disorder, delusion, or syndrome. You may want to edit the question to make clear that you're talking about a _common_ cognitive bias that affects nearly everyone.

Comment: If you check the [list of cognitive biases on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cognitive_biases), and look at the details, you'll notice that almost all such biases are variations on errors caused by the idiosyncracy of personal experience. THat is, they're -all- biases of the individual being special. There is one by name though the [bias blind spot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_blind_spot) which is unfortunately a meta-bias that oneself doesn't have the biases that others do. So close but no cigar.

Comment: In particular, the Attentional Bias, Illusion of Control, and Negativity Bias seem related, but not quite on target.

Comment: The generic term that I would use for this is _exceptionalism_, in the American Heritage Dictionary's sense of "The theory or belief that something, especially a nation, does not conform to a pattern or norm." I see that phrase "especially a nation" as well as anyone else does, but I think that the rest of the definition can apply to individual people, too.

Answer (score 3):

Falsely inferring a pattern where none exists is known as a ***type 1 error*** in statistics.

In this case the subject is under a delusion of self-reference, attributing undue importance to self in the events around him i.e. *centered in (on) oneself*, which is ***self-centring***.

The general term for this cognitive bias - of seeing patterns in random events or data - is ***apophenia*** (*apo* - away [hence *not true*] *phainein*- to show). So I guess your subject might be under a *self-centring apophenia*, or in other words guilty of *self-centring type 1 error*.There might me a more specific term for it but I can't think of any.

Answer (score 3):

[self-importance](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/selfimportant) : *'Excessively high regard for one's own importance or station; conceit'*

- an Anglo-Saxon synonym for: 'self-centred, vain, selfish, narcissistic, self-absorbed, egotistical, inward looking, self-important, self-obsessed, self-seeking, egoistic, egoistical'

and possibly also:

[presumptuous](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/presumptuous) : *'characterized by presumption or tending to presume; bold; forward'*

Answer (score 3):

What you're describing is a person who thinks of himself/herself as ***exceptional*** in the original sense of the word - in different situations (s)he might think of himself/herself as being better than others, worse than others, or different in a way that invalidates any comparison. These days "exceptional" is often used to mean "better than", but the original meaning survives in phrases like "American exceptionalism" or "European exceptionalism" (in this case, the term might be something like "self-exceptionalism").

As far as an actual scientific term, you seem to be looking for an umbrella term covering several psychological terms for more specific biases, including:

***Confirmation bias*** - The tendency to accept evidence that supports what we already believe and discard evidence that would force us to change our thinking.

***Self-serving bias*** - The tendency to believe that our successes come from our own attributes, while our failures are the result of external factors beyond our control.

Answer (score 2):

**[Egocentricity](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/egocentric)**

> regarding everything only in relation to oneself; self-centred; selfish

Comment: 'self-importance' is more Anglo-Saxon, see my answer for synonyms...

Answer (score 1):

How about [Narcissism](http://www.mayoclinic.com/health/narcissistic-personality-disorder/DS00652/DSECTION=symptoms)

> Narcissistic personality disorder symptoms may include:
>
> ```
> Believing that you're better than others
> Fantasizing about power, success and attractiveness
> Exaggerating your achievements or talents
> Expecting constant praise and admiration
> Believing that you're special and acting accordingly
> Failing to recognize other people's emotions and feelings
> Expecting others to go along with your ideas and plans
> Taking advantage of others
> Expressing disdain for those you feel are inferior
> Being jealous of others
> Believing that others are jealous of you
> Trouble keeping healthy relationships
> Setting unrealistic goals
> Being easily hurt and rejected
> Having a fragile self-esteem
> Appearing as tough-minded or unemotional
> ```

Comment: I think the question is looking for something more general – narcissism is a pretty specific disorder, but most people think they're somehow unique and special.

Comment: Agreed. I'm not looking for a *disorder*, I'm looking for the name of the trait that is common in nearly everyone such that they think that things that they don't *notice* in other people is believed to only *happen* to them.

Comment: Fair enough. How about *self-obsessed*?

Comment: Would the downvoters please explain their reasons? Downvoting without an explanation is not helpful either to me or the OP.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suspect that they're objecting for the reasons given by me and the OP above.

Comment: @BraddSzonye Thanks, though it seems a little harsh given that the edited clarification was given after I'd submitted my answer! Also one of the definitions of narcissism is that is a more extreme version of what most of us have in small amounts. But then I guess that's just typical, why is always me that gets downvoted? Everything would be much better if only people did things *my* way. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would say that such person suffers from [**delusions of grandeur**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandiose_delusions) or **grandiose delusions**.

> delusions of grandeur - a delusion (common in paranoia) that you are
>   much greater and more powerful and influential than you really are

If you just want one word I would go with **delusional**.  When used in context it has the same meaning.

Comment: Believe it or not some people actually do get bullied, especially some children. The tone of these answers seem quite complacent to me, and perhaps go some way to explain an instinct in humans not dissimilar from turkeys in a confined cage, where they will literally peck one of their number to death. What is a word which means 'having the characteristic of turkeys'?

Comment: OP has clarified that he's looking for the name of a **common** cognitive bias that affects most people, not an abnormal disorder or delusion.

Comment: @BraddSzonye  - You don't think most people are a little delusional?

Answer (score 0):

An important possibility not yet mentioned is the psychological concept of ***suffering from ideas (or delusions) of reference***.  Here the 'reference' concept is about the fact that external phenomena are interpreted as being targeted specially at the person so described.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideas_of_reference_and_delusions_of_reference