# A term for someone who demotivates

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, pejorative-language

What do we call a person who constantly demotivates others?

For context: someone who thinks he is so brilliant in English, keeps discouraging me about the questions/answers I post.

Comment: downer, killjoy, buzzkill, wet blanket

Comment: per the 'context': stimulator.

Comment: heh if you want to go tongue-in-cheek, start calling him your **_inspiration_**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Hypercritical***

[FTD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hypercritical) *inclined to judge too severely; "hypercritical of colloquial speech"; "the overcritical teacher can discourage originality"* also *Excessively and unreasonably critical, esp. of small faults.*

[M.W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hypercritical) says: *criticizing other people or things too strongly or too often*

A person who is hypercritical of everything one does, says, or writes can be extremely disheartening and demotivating. Think of a hypercritical parent, partner, teacher or manager whose exacting and severe behaviour can actively discourage initiative and creativity in their listeners.

Comment: Hypercritical looks good. Thanks for your feedback. :)

Answer (score 0):

*dismotivator* & *[demotivator](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/demotivator)* n

dictionary.reference.com lists *demotivator* as a noun.

*dismotivator* seems to be preferred in academic writing, esp., with reference to Frederick I Herzberg's motivation-hygiene theory ([Two-factor Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-factor_theory)).

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/demotivator):
1. One who, or that which, demotivates.

Word processors may flag the word, though, as many dictionaries stop at *demotivate*.

Plenty of use case results on Google:
https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&tab=ww&q="demotivator"+-despair

And growing!
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=demotivator&year_start=1960